# What should I do to get rid of this error message?

Tags: c

I am running a hollow box statement and cant figure out the error message

```
error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token"  {
```

I have tried multiple variations of the bracket in different positions and it just causes more errors. Here is the updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{

    int i;

    printf("Even numbers between 25 to 75: \n");
    for (i = 25; i<=75; i++)
    {
        if(i%2 == 0)
        {
            printf("%d\t", i);
        }
    }
    printf("All odd numbers between 500 to 400: \n");
    for (i = 500; i>=400; i--)
    {
        if(i%2 == 0)
        {
            printf("%d\t", i-1);
        }


    }
    int number, result, exponent;
    result = 1;

    printf("Enterthe base number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    printf("Enter the exponent: ");
    scanf("%d", &exponent);

    while (exponent != 0)
    {
        result *= number;
        --exponent;
    }

     printf("Answer = %d \n", result);
}


int f, w;
{
    for (f = 1; f <= 7; f++)
    {
        for (w = 1; w <= 7; w++)
        {
            if (f==1 || f==7 || w==1 || w==7)
                printf("*");
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
        }


    return 0;

}
```

This is an update to the first question since my first post didnt show the whole code and everyones answer was asking for it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is this all of your code? Works fine for me, although indentation is strongly recommended. The post title is also very generic and could be improved.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. If that is all of the code you are actually trying to compile, then it is not a complete C program. Executable code must be inside a function, and you need a function called `main`. The basics of setting up an elementary C program should be at the start of any tutorial or primer.

Comment: Are you not missing an `int main (void) {`? and then you can delete the `'{'` after `int f, w;` and indent your code properly (maybe even use an editor that highlights matching opening/closing braces) and lastly add `#include <stdio.h>` at the top, compile, link and run. (also, e.g.  `putchar('*');` is sufficient for a single-character)

Comment: I posted the entire code now, to show the indents and everything done so far

Comment: @FrankWeirich Fix the indentation and the cause of the error should be apparent.

Comment: thanks everyone, after looking at the indents and the brackets I have figure it out

Answer (score 2):

You should put an `int main(void)` before the body of your main function. You can then move your variables inside the function. After you've done this, the top of your code should look like:

```
int main(void) /* Here! */
{
int f, w; /* Move this inside the function. */
for (f = 1; f <= 7; f++)
...
```

Comment: Or at least [C-Box](https://paste.opensuse.org/88939137) `:)`